# Weak limit of continuous operator

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, weak-convergence, von-neumann-algebras, weak-topology

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the von Neumann algebra of bounded operators on a Hilbert Space and $\mathcal{A}_{*}$ its predual.
Further consider a weakly convergent sequence of continuous and bounded operators $V^{m}:[0,T]\rightarrow\mathcal{A}_{*}.$ I know that the limit $V$ is bounded (with that I mean that every element in $V([0,T])$ is bounded) by the Uniform boundedness principle but is the limit continuous as well? 
This might be an easy consequence or just plain wrong. I feel like I'm missing something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need some notion of uniform convergence to ensure that the limit $V$ is continuous.  For example, fix $a\in\mathcal A_*$ non-zero, and define $V^m:[0,1]\to \mathcal A_*$ by $V^m(t)=t^ma$.  Then the sequence $(V^m)$ converges pointwise to $V:[0,1]\to\mathcal A_*$  defined by
\begin{align*}
V(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}0&:&t\in[0,1),\\
a&:&t=1,
\end{array}\right.
\end{align*}
which is certainly not continuous.

Comment: I see. Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help!